# One to many relationship with the mandatory participation at the 1: site

Tags: sql, javadb

I am new to SQL and I would like to develop a database with two tables(project, task). One to many relationship. How can I create a constraint in SQL (javaDB, Apache Derby) to check that each project must have at least one or more task and each task must be assigned to at most one project. This is just an example but I am interested mainly in the mandatory participation at the 1: site. 
In SQL Anywhere I can use Check Exist constraint something like this: CHECK(EXIST(SELECT * FROM task WHERE project.project_pk = task.task_pk). The problem is that CHECK EXIST constraint is not in Apache Derby.

Comment: You're going to have a chicken-and-a-egg problem here. At some point you want to create a new project, and this logically has to exist in the database (though in a transaction) before the tasks have been added.

Comment: As for the "task must be assigned to at most one project", that's easily doable and requires no extra work. Simply add the foreign key that references the project into the task table, and you would have only one column to set, for each task. This would make it impossible for you to link the same row in the task table to more than one project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can't have both of these constraints in effect at the same time.

consider how these will be created - whichever one you create first will fail the constraint.

I think typically, the parent object, in your example the project, would not have a constraint about the children.  however the child, in your example the task, would contain a NOT NULL column that was a Foreign Key to the parent.